# Concatenating a char and float to print out in opengl/glut

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I am trying to print the fps of my program in the window.

So I am trying to output something like this: `Fps: 16.72`

I have created a method to deal with displaying the text:

```
void displayText( float x, float y, char *string ) {
    char * ch;

    glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
    glRasterPos3f( x, y, 0.0 );

    for( ch = string; *ch; ch++ ) {
        glutBitmapCharacter( GLUT_BITMAP_TIMES_ROMAN_24, (int)*ch );
    }
}
```

which is called with:

```
displayText( 900, 900, str);
```

and I'm trying to convert the floating point number `fps` to a char to pass to this method.
Various methods I've tried:

```
char * str = "Fps: "; // and the fps is a float instantiated by another method

char * newFPS = (char)fps; // I tried to cast
strcat(str,newFPS);        // and then concatenate them
snprintf(str, sizeof(str), "%f", fps); // googled example
sprintf( str, "%f", (char)fps);        // another one
```

I don't really understand C and it's functions enough to know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: ahh I forgot to say, they all compile fine but end with a Seg fault.

Comment: Not enough memory allocated for the string. Trying to write a read-only string literal. Asked dozens of times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

```
char buf[100] = {0};
snprintf(buf, 100, "FPS: %.1f", fps);
displayText( 900, 900, buf);
```

Comment: Ahhhhhhhh damn that makes sense. Well, I must have tried everything but that... feel a bit silly ;) cheers